# Index sorting where numbers are indexed

Tags: indexing, sorting

I have a vast document where I have a separate index of dates (really only the year or year range of particular events). 
I'm using `memoir`.

Sometimes the year is known exactly

```
\index[dates]{1875!Event xyz}
```

Sometimes the year is a range

```
\index[dates]{1822--1867!Event abc}
```

These sort in index as

> 1822-1897
>     Event xxxx 77,87
>     Event pppp 73
>
> 1829-1844
>     Event zzz 79
>
> 1756
>     Event xxx2  99

In other words, date ranges sort alphabetically and are separated from the single numeric entries which sort numerically yielding an odd ordering. Is there any way I get numbers to sort alphabetically and not numerically so that I can get ordering

> 1
>  1--5
>  2
>  3
>  3--5
>  4

rather than

> 1--5
>  3--5
>  1
>  2
>  3
>  4

The index entries are via a macro

```
\newcommand{\indexdate}[2]{#1\index[dates]{#1!{#2}}}
```

And so a single change to the macro might achieve what I want without having to manually edit every one of a couple of thousands of entries to impose a sort order.

I have hit a roadblock on this one. I don't think a MWE would be of additional use here, but happy to post one.

Comment: An MWE is _always_ of use, especially if you want people to test their answers before posting.

Comment: you might consider adding a sort field with a space at the end, so that you would get `\index[dates]{1875 @1875!Event xyz}`, so that a single year would always sort before a year span.  (i'm not sure i understand how 1756 sorts *after* 1829 in any case.)

Comment: Barbara's space idea works brilliantly (or via my macro which is now \newcommand{\indexdate}[2]{#1\index[dates]{#1 @#1!{#2}}}. (I take the comment about MWEs). Barbara, yes 1756 does indeed sort AFTER 1829--1844, but the space idea solves it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Makeindex sorts numbers in numerical order:

```
1
9
10
```

However ranges are not numbers. The range symbol `--` prevents Makeindex to take such an entry as number. These entries are sorted in lexical order. Also they precede the numbers.

You can specify a sort key for Makeindex. If the sort key is a number, then the number of digits should be the same for years and year ranges, e.g.:

```
\newcommand{\indexdate}[2]{#1\index[dates]{#10000@#1!#2}}
\newcommand{\indexdaterange}[3]{#1--#2\index[dates]{#1#2@#1--#2!#3}}
```

The sortkey is the entry before `@`. The sort key of a year range is just the two four-digit years. In case of a year, the sort key is the four-digit year, followed by four zeros to fill the eight digits for all numerical sort keys.

Alternatively the sort key can add a non-digit, then the entries are sorted in lexical order, with four-digit years, the numerical order is not really needed:

```
\newcommand{\indexdate}[2]{#1\index[dates]{#1x@#1!#2}}
```

Comment: heiko-oberdiek solution also works well and provides a useful template for the future. 

For my particular problem simply adding a space as suggested by @barbara-beeton is what I'm going for. The same macro:

\newcommand{\indexdate}[2]{#1\index[dates]{#1 @#1!{#2}}}

serves for both single numbers and ranges, similar to heiko-oberdiek second solution.

Many thanks to both. I'm not sure how to mark answers as solutions.

Answer (score 1):

[Xindy](http://xindy.sourceforge.net/) is already ready for such cases thanks to merging and sorting rules. I enclose an example and a preview of the last page. Please run it with shell escape on, or, run these three lines on this example (`pdflatex` and `xelatex` can be used right away too as font related packages are not activated yet):

> lualatex mal-xindy-numbers.tex
>   xindy -M texindy -L general -C utf8 -M mal-style -o dates.ind dates.idx
>   lualatex mal-xindy-numbers.tex

```
%! *latex mal-xindy-numbers.tex
%  with shell escape on
\documentclass{memoir}
%\usepackage{xltxtra} % use: inputenc (pdflatex), fontspec (xelatex)
\usepackage[hyperindex=false,colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{firstpagestyle=empty}
\makeatletter\def\imki@progdefault{xindy}\makeatother
\makeindex[name=dates, title=Milestone events, options=-M texindy -L general -C utf8 -M mal-style]
\def\indexdate#1#2{#1\index[dates]{#1!#2}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{mal-style.xdy}
(markup-locref :attr "default" :open "\hyperpage{" :close "}")
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\indexdate{1}{Event A}
\indexdate{1}{Event I}
\indexdate{1--5}{Event I}
\indexdate{1--5}{Event X}
\indexdate{1--5}{Event B}
\indexdate{2}{Event C}
\indexdate{3}{Event D}
\indexdate{3--5}{Event E}
\indexdate{4}{Event F}
\indexdate{1950}{Event G}
\indexdate{1950}{Event K}
\newpage
\indexdate{1950}{Event G}
\indexdate{1950}{Event K}
\indexdate{1950--1955}{Event G}
\indexdate{1948}{Event L}
\indexdate{1949--1951}{Event G}
\indexdate{1949--1950}{Event H}
\printindex[dates]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]